# DrRacket - creating a list within a list using minimal built in functions

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I need a function that will do this:

Odd Length list
Input '(1 2 3 4 5) = '(1 (2 (3) 4) 5)

Even length list
Input '(1 2 3 4) = '(1 (2 () 3) 4)

It needs to use very minimal built in functions.  I have spent hours trying to figure this out and I am completely out of ideas at this point.

Here is what I have:

```
(define (listInList L)
    (define length (listLength L))     
    (define L2 (listInListHelper length L '() '()))
    (define L3 (listInListHelper (- length 2) L L2 '()))
    L3
)

(define (listInListHelper N L NL)
(cond
    ((= N 0) '()
    ((= N 1) (cons (list (car L)) NL))
    (else (cons (cons (car L) (list (lastItem L))) NL)
    (remove 1 L)))     
)
)

(define (lastItem L)
(if (null? (cdr L))(car L)
    (lastItem (cdr L)))
)

(define (remove N L)
(cond ((eq? N 0) (cdr L))
    (else (cons (car L) (remove (- N 1)(cdr L))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way to do it, you need to tell me if it's minimal enough:

```
(define (f lst)
  (define (helper lst rlst half)
    (cond
      ((= half 0 )  null)
      ((= half 1/2) (list (car lst)))
      (else         (list (car lst)
                          (helper (cdr lst) (cdr rlst) (sub1 half))
                          (car rlst)))))
  (helper lst (reverse lst) (/ (length lst) 2)))
```

testing:

```
> (f '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(1 (2 (3) 4) 5)
> (f '(1 2 3 4))
'(1 (2 () 3) 4)
```

Comment: Yes it is, thank you so much! I was ready to throw my laptop against the wall while I was working on this.

Comment: I think I got it down by one build-in procedure.

Comment: Yes and I think I can manage to write my own version of it, thank you again

Comment: could you help me with another problem I am having?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740700/drracket-why-is-this-number-negative