# DrRacket - why is this number negative?

Tags: scheme, racket

So I can not figure out why my numbers are negative in this function.  Also, the input for calculate is supposed to be a list of the same 3 if someone could give me a hand with that as well, it would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

`calculate` takes the first number in the list, then multiplies it by the second number in the list and subtracts the third number from the input list.

`((calculate '(8 3 7)) '(4 8 2 9))` should return `'(29 41 23 44)`

```
(define (calculateHelper n m o L)
  (if (null? L) empty
      (cons ((calculate n m o) (car L)) 
            (calculateHelper n m o (cdr L)))))

;((calculate 8 3 7) '(4 8 2 9))
(define (calculate n m o)
   (lambda (L)
     (if (list? L) (calculate n m o L)
         (- o (* m (+ n L))))))
```

Comment: Which number is negative?

Comment: What does "a list of the same 3" mean? How *exactly* is the example output related to the example input?

Comment: There are many arity errors in your code. eg. your "test" passes one argument  to `caclulate` while itself has 3 parameters. The function it returns calls `calculate` with 4 arguments, one too much, if `L` is a `list?` Since your description only describes operation on "the list" why are there two lists? What should happen if there are less than 3 elements in the list?

Comment: What is `calculateHelper` for? Did you mean to call that instead of the recursive call to `calculate`? And what is `makeSmasher`?

Comment: Sorry, makeSmasher was the original name I was replacing it with calculate so that the name would look less weird.

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, your subtraction was inverted. This should help:

```
(define (calculate n m o)
  (lambda (L)
    (map (lambda (e)
           (- (* m (+ n e)) o))
         L)))
```

then

```
> ((calculate 8 3 7) '(4 8 2 9))
'(29 41 23 44)
```

---

**EDIT**: to call `calculate` with a list, you could for example use `apply` to destructure:

```
(define (calculate nums)
  (apply (lambda (n m o) 
           (lambda (L)
             (map (lambda (e)
                    (- (* m (+ n e)) o))
                  L)))
         nums))
```

then

```
> ((calculate '(8 3 7)) '(4 8 2 9))
'(29 41 23 44)
```

Comment: how could it be changed so that the input of calculate is a list with those same 3 numbers.  So the call would look like this ((calculate '(8 3 7)) '(4 8 2 9)?